# I have used the font awesome class of bootstrap.But the logos are not getting displayed in the chrome browser

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

these logos are not getting displayed

```
  <h3>Around the Web</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="button social" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/hallaathrad"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>  /*i tag is used for logos.*/
            <li><a class="button social" href="https://twitter.com/hallaathrad><i class="fa fa-fw fa-github"></i></a></li> /*i tag is used for logos.*/
            <li><a class="button social" href="https://twitter.com/hallaathrad"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter"></i></a></li> /*i tag is used for logos.*/
            <li><a class="button social" href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/hallaathrad/" title="My Flickr"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-flickr"></i></a></li> /*i tag is used for logos.*/
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing quotation mark on the second anchor element.

```
"https://twitter.com/hallaathrad" // <-- need closing quote
```

Are you sure you've loaded the FontAwesome resource? Note [this demo of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/4fe4dr4t/), which works fine.

Comment: even after doing that,none of the logos are getting displayed! Is it an issue related to the browser.I am using chrome in this case @hafiz

Comment: what exactly is meant by loading font awesome resource

Comment: Make sure you're on the latest Chrome version, and try clearing your cache. Works fine for me on v56. As for loading the resource, you need to have a link to the FontAwesome stylesheet, otherwise the font won't load.